# Plotly function is not giving a desired plot

Tags: ggplot2, plotly

Problem: All values of aesthetically mapped variable not displayed, I mapped the variable 'class' of mpg data set of ggplot2, but the plotly function is not displaying all of them. The drv(drivetrain) has three distinct values '4', 'f', 'r', but the plot is showing the legend only for 'r'(look at top right hand side).
Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# using mpg data set, already loaded as a part of ggplot2

fig<-plot_ly(mpg,x=~cty, y=~hwy, 
             color=~drv,
             frame = ~class,
             type="scatter",
             mode="markers")
fig
```

Below is the screenshot, following warning was shown:
`Warning message: In p$x$data[firstFrame] <- p$x$frames[[1]]$data : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`
[image]

There should have been points or markers with three different colors but only 1 is being shown at a time.